# Ricci flat compact manifold with $U(1)\times{}SU(2)\times{}SU(3)$ isometry group?

Tags: differential-geometry, symmetry, group-theory, metric-tensor, compactification

As the title says, is it possible to have a Riemannian Ricci flat compact manifold with $U(1)\times{}SU(2)\times{}SU(3) $ [isometry group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry_group)?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no, and it follows from a classical result in Riemannian geometry: the continuous isometry group of a compact Ricci-flat Riemannian manifold can be at most a $n$-torus $T^{n}$, namely abelian, so the group of the Standard Model ;) is not allowed.